# What is the best way to share a text file between cluster nodes?

Tags: chef-infra

The chef recipe creates a text file on one node which is the used by two other nodes.
I am thinking of storing the text file in an encrypted data bag when it is generated on the first node.
The encrypted data bag is then loaded on the 2 other nodes.

I am trying to use the following post as a reference:
[how to create\edit encrypted data bag item from a chef recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359763/how-to-create-edit-encrypted-data-bag-item-from-a-chef-recipe)

Please suggest if it is correct way to share the text file on 2 other nodes after it is generated on the 1st node.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly supported by Chef, though you could use a combination of features and reconfigurations to support it. The better way is to have Chef manage the file's content on all nodes. Basically top-down instead of bottom-up.

Comment: can you provide some reference/example where you or someone else might have used it

Comment: I mean the actual code would just be a `template`, `cookbook_file`, or `file` resource. Just check out any major Chef tutorial for an example.

Answer (score 0):

are you doing it on cloud ? If yes, you could push that file to s3 and then pull it on rest of your nodes , or if you are not on cloud , you can still push it other places like svn/git/nexus etc and access it on rest of your nodes.